# TypescriptBuild:Type '{ Id: number; title: string; Name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript1.4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QTYi.png)I am trying to run below code in VS2017 typescript for Angular 2, getting an error. I have created CustomerViewModel also. I am unable to create an array list of class CustomerViewModel.
Here is the code,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU5ut.png)

Comment: I have attached screen shot of code and error in details.

Comment: If I read the error message correctly then you need to provide a 'heroes' property as well. You might also wanto to post the code in plain text or on some sample sites. Screenshots are not the preferred way of asking a good question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://jsbin.com/?html,output for more information.

Comment: I have attached screen shot of Cusotmerviewmodel class.

Comment: I am sorry for attaching the screen shot image. Next time I will take care of this. Sorry once again